# Spotfire Calculate column: Time difference OVER column value

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

Folks,

I have a data table:

[image: My data table]

I am trying to achieve recurring calculations and having trouble doing so.

I have managed to do it per single master code as a calculated column, and trying to achieve all the calculated time differences to be in single calculated column as image above.

Any help appreciated!

Thanks.

PS: The data is spanned over a range (1-200 days etc) and a 5 second difference from one row to another with a possible change in Master code. I am trying to obtain the period per code per iteration.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: so the calculated column is the expected results you are trying to achieve, correct?

Comment: indeed, scsimon!

Comment: is this per day, or if this spanned multiple days you would want just one for the entire range?

Comment: This is spanned over a period of days with 5sec interval between every row. If it was for entire range, I could go for _Min & Max with Over expression_. I have only provided you with one single days data and that too with a larger difference in time range, whereas my data set carries a 5 sec range difference from row to row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here are the steps you need to take

- Insert calculated column #1 below and name it `ROWID`
- Insert calculated column #2 below and name it `DateTime`
- Insert calculated column #3 below and name it `Grouping`
- Insert calculated column #4 below and name it `DateDifference`

**Expression 1**

```
RowId()
```

**Expression 2**

```
DateTime(Concatenate([Date]," ",[Time]))
```

**Expression 3**

```
Min(If(([Master code]<>Max([Master code]) over (Next([ROWID]))) or ([ROWID]=Max([ROWID])),[ROWID] - Min([ROWID]) over (AllPrevious([ROWID])))) OVER (AllNext([ROWID]))
```

**Expression 4**

```
Abs(DateDiff(Min([DateTime]) OVER (Intersect([Grouping],AllPrevious([ROWID]))),[DateTime]))
```

> If you really only want to populate the rows you listed above, then
>   continue from here...

- Insert calculated column #5 and name it `RowsToKeep`

**Expression 5**

```
If(([Master code]<>Max([Master code]) over (Next([ROWID]))) or ([ROWID]=Max([ROWID])),[DateDifference])
```

**RESULTS**

```
+-------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+------------+
| ROWID |    Date    |    Time     |     DateTime     | Master code | Grouping | DateDifference | RowsToKeep |
+-------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+------------+
|     1 | 12/07/2017 | 1:05:40 AM  | 12/07/2017 1:05  |         100 |        0 | 0:00:00        |            |
|     2 | 12/07/2017 | 4:45:20 AM  | 12/07/2017 4:45  |         100 |        0 | 3:39:40        |            |
|     3 | 12/07/2017 | 6:20:10 AM  | 12/07/2017 6:20  |         100 |        0 | 5:14:30        | 5:14:30    |
|     4 | 12/07/2017 | 6:20:11 AM  | 12/07/2017 6:20  |         400 |        4 | 0:00:00        |            |
|     5 | 12/07/2017 | 8:15:12 AM  | 12/07/2017 8:15  |         400 |        4 | 1:55:01        |            |
|     6 | 12/07/2017 | 9:12:10 AM  | 12/07/2017 9:12  |         400 |        4 | 2:51:59        |            |
|     7 | 12/07/2017 | 9:45:45 AM  | 12/07/2017 9:45  |         400 |        4 | 3:25:34        | 3:25:34    |
|     8 | 12/07/2017 | 9:45:46 AM  | 12/07/2017 9:45  |         120 |        6 | 0:00:00        |            |
|     9 | 12/07/2017 | 10:20:35 AM | 12/07/2017 10:20 |         120 |        6 | 0:34:49        | 0:34:49    |
|    10 | 12/07/2017 | 10:20:36 AM | 12/07/2017 10:20 |         100 |       10 | 0:00:00        |            |
|    11 | 12/07/2017 | 10:25:45 AM | 12/07/2017 10:25 |         100 |       10 | 0:05:09        |            |
|    12 | 12/07/2017 | 11:15:55 AM | 12/07/2017 11:15 |         100 |       10 | 0:55:19        |            |
|    13 | 12/07/2017 | 12:22:22 PM | 12/07/2017 12:22 |         100 |       10 | 2:01:46        | 2:01:46    |
|    14 | 12/07/2017 | 12:22:23 PM | 12/07/2017 12:22 |         350 |       16 | 0:00:00        |            |
|    15 | 12/07/2017 | 3:35:40 PM  | 12/07/2017 15:35 |         350 |       16 | 3:13:17        |            |
|    16 | 12/07/2017 | 3:42:25 PM  | 12/07/2017 15:42 |         350 |       16 | 3:20:02        |            |
|    17 | 12/07/2017 | 4:38:17 PM  | 12/07/2017 16:38 |         350 |       16 | 4:15:54        |            |
|    18 | 12/07/2017 | 4:52:35 PM  | 12/07/2017 16:52 |         350 |       16 | 4:30:12        |            |
|    19 | 12/07/2017 | 4:52:40 PM  | 12/07/2017 16:52 |         350 |       16 | 4:30:17        | 4:30:17    |
|    20 | 12/07/2017 | 4:52:41 PM  | 12/07/2017 16:52 |         100 |       19 | 0:00:00        |            |
|    21 | 12/07/2017 | 7:23:23 PM  | 12/07/2017 19:23 |         100 |       19 | 2:30:42        |            |
|    22 | 12/07/2017 | 8:23:20 PM  | 12/07/2017 20:23 |         100 |       19 | 3:30:39        | 3:30:39    |
+-------+------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+----------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: **for expression4** : spotfire is rendering error: _invalid type for function call 'Abs' _

Comment: Worked for me. Just remove the ABS and multiply by -1